# Shebang won't work

Tags: python, python-2.x, shebang

I have written a small python script but bash won't execute it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

'''
Created on Dec 19, 2014


'''
import subprocess


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = subprocess.Popen('df -h', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    out,err = p.communicate()
    for o in out.splitlines():
        if('rootfs' in o):
            print o.split()[3]
```

When I run `./te.py`, bash gives me an error:

```
-bash: ./te.py: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What's the problem?

Comment: that `^M` means that your line endings have problems

Comment: What version of Python are you using ? It could be `#!/usr/bin/python3` if you are using Python 3.x

Comment: Python 2, as there are no brackets around the print.

Comment: Try editing your lines in vi or vim (create new line endings)

Comment: i edit this script with nano ...

Comment: i reedit this script via another editor and works...
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of the line endings. If the OP had line ending issues before, chances are they'll have line ending issues with this version.